# Accessibility (Voice Over) with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, uiaccessibility

I'm attempting to add support for Voice Over accessibility in a puzzle game which has a fixed board.  However, I'm having trouble getting `UIAccessibilityElements` to show up.

Right now I'm overriding `accessibilityElementAtIndex`, `accessibilityElementCount` and `indexOfAccessibilityElement` in my SKScene.

They are returning an array of accessible elements as such:

```
func loadAccessibleElements()
{
    self.isAccessibilityElement = false

    let pieces = getAllPieces()

    accessibleElements.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for piece in pieces
    {
        let element = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self.usableView!)

        element.accessibilityFrame = piece.getAccessibilityFrame()
        element.accessibilityLabel = piece.getText()
        element.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        accessibleElements.append(element)
    }
}
```

Where piece is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and `getAccessibilityFrame` is defined:

```
func getAccessibilityFrame() -> CGRect
{
    return parentView!.convertRect(frame, toView: nil)
}
```

Right now one (wrongly sized) `accessibility` element seems to appear on the screen in the wrong place.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

EDIT:
I've tried a hack-ish work around by placing a UIView over the SKView with UIButton elements in the same location as the SKSpriteNodes.  However, accessibility still doesn't want to work.  The view is loaded as such:

```
func loadAccessibilityView()
{
    view.isAccessibilityElement = false
    view.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
    skView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
    let accessibleSubview = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    accessibleSubview.userInteractionEnabled = true
    accessibleSubview.isAccessibilityElement = false
    view.addSubview(accessibleSubview)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(accessibleSubview)

    let pieces = (skView.scene! as! GameScene).getAllPieces()
    for piece in pieces
    {
        let pieceButton = UIButton(frame: piece.getAccessibilityFrame())
        pieceButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
        pieceButton.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
        pieceButton.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        pieceButton.setTitle(piece.getText(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        pieceButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "blue-button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        pieceButton.alpha = 0.2
        pieceButton.accessibilityLabel = piece.getText()
        pieceButton.accessibilityFrame = pieceButton.frame
        pieceButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didTap:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        accessibleSubview.addSubview(pieceButton)
    }

    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, nil)

}
```

The buttons are placed correctly, however accessibility just isn't working at all. Something seems to be preventing it from working.

Comment: Further to this, I have tried another way - I added a subview of UIButtons in  overlaying the exact same position as the skspritenodes.  I was surprised that these buttons too cannot be accessed by voice over.  Have I made a mistake blocking inputs?  The skscene itself does override touchesBegun(...) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched in vain for a description of how to implement VoiceOver in Swift using SpriteKit, so I finally figured out how to do it.  Here's some working code that converts a SKNode to an accessible pushbutton when added to a SKScene class:

```
// Add the following code to a scene where you want to make the SKNode variable named “leave” an accessible button
// leave must already be initialized and added as a child of the scene, or a child of other SKNodes in the scene
// screenHeight must already be defined as the height of the device screen, in points

// Accessibility

private var accessibleElements: [UIAccessibilityElement] = []

private func nodeToDevicePointsFrame(node: SKNode) -> CGRect {

    // first convert from frame in SKNode to frame in SKScene's coordinates

    var sceneFrame = node.frame
    sceneFrame.origin = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.frame.origin, fromNode: node.parent!)

    // convert frame from SKScene coordinates to device points
    // sprite kit scene origin is in lower left, accessibility device screen origin is at upper left
    // assumes scene is initialized using SKSceneScaleMode.Fill using dimensions same as device points

    var deviceFrame = sceneFrame
    deviceFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(screenHeight-1) - (sceneFrame.origin.y + sceneFrame.size.height)
    return deviceFrame
}

private func initAccessibility() {
    if accessibleElements.count == 0 {
        let accessibleLeave = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self.view!)
        accessibleLeave.accessibilityFrame = nodeToDevicePointsFrame(leave)
        accessibleLeave.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        accessibleLeave.accessibilityLabel = “leave” // the accessible name of the button
        accessibleElements.append(accessibleLeave)
    }
}
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.isAccessibilityElement = false
    leave.isAccessibilityElement = true
}

override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    accessibleElements = []
}

override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
    initAccessibility()
    return accessibleElements.count
}

override func accessibilityElementAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    initAccessibility()
    if (index < accessibleElements.count) {
        return accessibleElements[index] as AnyObject
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

override func indexOfAccessibilityElement(element: AnyObject) -> Int {
    initAccessibility()
    return accessibleElements.indexOf(element as! UIAccessibilityElement)!
}
```

Comment: In my case it was enough to override `accessibilityFrame` on node subclass and setup it's label and traits.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility frames are defined in the fixed **physical screen coordinates**, not UIView coordinates, and transforming between them is kind of tricky.

The device origin is the lower left of the screen, with X up, when the device is in landscape right mode.

It's a pain converting, I've no idea why Apple did it that way.

Comment: Yeah they're a hassle, I've tried a few variations on the getAccessibilityFrame function - all of which didn't work properly.  I've managed to get UIButtons overlaid on the sprite elements instead, but accessibility doesn't work for them either.  I feel like maybe the SKScene is confusing the inputs?  On tap and drag it just makes a noise like you've tried to select an empty area without accessibility.  I'll expand on it in my question soon

Comment: I was lucky in that the app spec just wants landscape left&right, so it was easy to hand code the transformation when they didn't consistently work.

Comment: The accessibility element is just a focus area for a tap or gesture, so anything that blocks it would indeed keep it from working. Are you sure your accessibility container, if you have one, is returning "no"?

Comment: In Swift I couldn't seem to override it directly to return false, but I set the variable isAccessibilityElement to false for the UIView associated with the container object.  With my new (albeit hackish) UIButton method, I assumed the accessibility would automatically be dealt with like buttons in other view controllers, but something seems amiss.  I'll edit my main post to include some of the details

Comment: I never resolved this on iOS6 or iOS7, but the VO focus and switch focus works as expected with iOS 8 and above, i.e. follows the window and not the device orientation.